# some objects does not appear in iOS build

Tags: c#, iphone, xcode, unity-game-engine

I develop a bow and arrow game. In Unity (Unity3D) everything is fine but when I build and run it on a device, and also in the simulator, some graphics like the bowstring are missing in the game. Any ideas about what's going on. Any clues are appreciated.

```
bowStringLinerenderer = bowString.AddComponent<LineRenderer>();
    bowStringLinerenderer.SetVertexCount(3);
    bowStringLinerenderer.SetWidth(0.05F, 0.05F);
    bowStringLinerenderer.useWorldSpace = false;
    bowStringLinerenderer.material = Resources.Load ("Materials/bowStringMaterial") as Material;
    bowStringPosition = new List<Vector3> ();
    bowStringPosition.Add(new Vector3 (-0.44f, 1.43f, 2f));
    bowStringPosition.Add(new Vector3 (-0.44f, -0.06f, 2f));
    bowStringPosition.Add(new Vector3 (-0.43f, -1.32f, 2f));
    bowStringLinerenderer.SetPosition (0, bowStringPosition [0]);
    bowStringLinerenderer.SetPosition (1, bowStringPosition [1]);
    bowStringLinerenderer.SetPosition (2, bowStringPosition [2]);
    arrowStartX = 0.7f;
```

Answer (score 0):

as explained by the unity docs:

Most assets
 in Unity are combined into the project when it is built. However, it is sometimes useful to place files into the normal filesystem on the target machine to make them accessible via a pathname. An example of this is the deployment of a movie file on iOS
 devices; the original movie file must be available from a location in the filesystem to be played by the PlayMovie function.

Any files placed in a folder called StreamingAssets (case-sensitive) in a Unity project will be copied verbatim to a particular folder on the target machine. You can retrieve the folder using the Application.streamingAssetsPath property. It’s always best to use Application.streamingAssetsPath to get the location of the StreamingAssets folder, as it will always point to the correct location on the platform where the application is running.

reference and to read more here: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StreamingAssets.html - hope it helps.

Comment: All good, let me know if it works. I am also interested to see as I have not had this issue before.

Comment: I got the actual problem the line rendering is not work on build check out the above code